# Scroll-based hide/show not working on IOS

Tags: html, macos

```css
:root {
    --primary-color: #080c11;
    --primary-color-highlight: #233D54;
    --bs-body-bg: #ffffff;
    
    --bs-body-font-family: 'times', serif;
    --bs-body-font-size: 1.1rem;
    
  }
  
  html {scroll-behavior: smooth;}
 


  body {overflow-x: hidden;}
  a { color: var(--primary-color); text-decoration: none; }
  a:hover { color: var(--primary-color); }
  .active:hover { color: #8d8d8d!important;  }




  /*  Navigation mennupoints and dropdown menu*/
  
  
 

  .artist-name {
    position: fixed;
    top: 1.3rem;
    left: 0.5rem;
    z-index: 999;
  }
  @media (min-width: 768px) { 
    .artist-name {
      top: 1.3rem;
      left: 2rem;
      z-index: 999;
    }
  }
  @media only screen 
  and (min-device-width : 768px) 
  and (max-device-width : 1024px)
  and (orientation : portrait) {
  /* Styles */.artist-name {
      top: 1.3rem;
      left: 2rem;
      z-index: 999;
      display: none;
    }
}

.navbar-brand {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif!important;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  @media (min-width: 768px) { 
    .navbar-brand {
      letter-spacing: .1rem;
      font-size: 1.4rem;
      
    }
  }

  .navbar {
    z-index: 998;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    min-height: 5rem;
  }
  @media (min-width: 768px) { 
    .navbar{height: 5rem;}
}
  
@media (max-width: 768px) { 
    .navbar-nav {background: white; padding-top: 3rem;overflow-y: scroll!important;}
}

@media (max-width: 768px) { 
  .full-width {  height: 100vh; background: rgb(255, 255, 255)!important; margin-top: 2rem!important;} 
}







  .nav-link {
    text-decoration: none; color: var(--primary-color); 
  }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 14px;
  }

  .menupoints {
    font-size: 1.5rem!important;
    line-height: 2.6rem;
    text-align: center;
  }
  @media (min-width: 768px) { 
    .menupoints{
      font-size: 1.8rem!important;
      line-height: 4rem;
  }}
  @media (min-width: 992px) { 
    .menupoints{
      
      font-size: 1.1rem!important;
  }}
  .navbar-toggler {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    }
 









/* Intro img*/

  
.centered {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: -50;
}
      
.intro-img-container {
  padding-top: 3em;
}

.intro-img {
  height: 100vh;
}














/* Year slider*/

.year-slider-container {

  position: fixed;
  top: 5rem;
  transition: top 0.55s ease; /* Transition effect when sliding down (and up) */
  z-index: 500;
}

.year-slider {

  position: relative;
  height: 8rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
  
}
@media (min-width: 992px) { 
  .year-slider {height: 6rem;
}}




.ui-slider-handle {
  width:2em!important;
  height: 2em!important;
  border-radius: 50%!important;
  top:-.7em!important;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-align:center!important;
}

.ui-state-default { background: white!important; border: 0.5px solid rgb(170, 170, 170)!Important;}

.ui-state-default .ui-slider-handle  .ui-state-focus .ui-corner-all .ui-state-hover .ui-state-active .ui-button .ui-corner-all .ui-slider-handle .ui-widget-content {

  border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204)!important;
}




/*modal and carousel*/


.modal-body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);}

@media (min-width: 992px) { 
.modal-body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80vw;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
}

.modal-content {position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100vw;
 }

 .mh-100 { max-height:70vh!important; }
 .ratio-16x9 {background-color: transparent!important; height: 70vh!important; }
 @media (min-width: 768px) { 
  .mh-100 { max-height:90vh!important;
  }
  .ratio-16x9 {background-color: transparent!important; height: 90vh!important; }

}
@media (min-width: 992px) { 
  .mh-100 { max-height:100vh!important;
  }
  .ratio-16x9 {background-color: transparent!important; height: 100vh!important; }
}



.img-fluid {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;}


  .img-fluid-landing {

   
    width: 100vw!important; left: 0%!important;
          top: 0%!important;
    }
   @media (min-width: 768px) { 
      .img-fluid-landing {width: 100vw!important; left: 0%!important;
        top: 0%!important;}
    }
    @media (min-width: 992px) { 
        .img-fluid-landing {width: 100vw!important;height: auto!important;  left: 0%!important;
          top: 0%!important;}
    }
    @media (min-width: 1400px) { 
      .img-fluid-landing {width: 100vw!important; left: 0%!important;
        top: 0%!important;}
    }
    @media (min-width: 1800px) { 
        .img-fluid-landing {width: 100vw!important; left: 0%!important;
          top: 0%!important;}
    }
     
 


 .work-info{
  font-size: 1rem!important;
  margin: 1em 0 1em;}

 @media (min-width: 768px) { 
  .work-info{
    font-size: 1rem!important;
    margin: 1em 0 1em;
}}
@media (min-width: 992px) { 
  .work-info{
    font-size: 1rem!important;
    margin: 1em 0 1em;
}}

.portfolio-wrapper {
  padding-top: 14rem;}

  @media (min-width: 768px) { 
    .portfolio-wrapper{
      padding-top: 13rem;
  }}

  @media (min-width: 960px) { 
    .portfolio-wrapper{
      padding-top: 10rem;
      
  }}
  .portfolio-img {
   
    width: 100%;
    }
  @media (min-width: 992px) { 
    .portfolio-img{
      width: 50%;
  }}

  .publication-img{
       width: 100%;
    }
  @media (min-width: 992px) { 
    .publication-img{
      max-width: 100%;
      
  }}


 .content-photo {
    padding-bottom: 2em;
  }
  
  .carousel-control-next,
  .carousel-control-prev /*, .carousel-indicators */ {
      filter: invert(100%);
  }
  .carousel-control-next{
    right: 10%;
  }
  .carousel-control-prev{
    left: 10%;
  }



  /*page transition / fade */


  .animate-in {
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn .5s ease-in;
    animation: fadeIn .5s ease-in;
}

.animate-out {
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
    transition: opacity .5s;
    opacity: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}

.sans-s-title {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif!important;
  letter-spacing: .2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
  .sans-s-title {
    letter-spacing: .1rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>KOUSHNA NAVABI </title>

  <!-- Bootstrap Stylesheet -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Main Stylesheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alegreya:wght@700&family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@400;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  
  
  
  
  
  <!-- Bootstrap Icons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.7.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">



   <!-- Year slider -->


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 1990,
      max: 2023,
      values: [ 1990, 2023 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val(ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
      " - " + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
  } );
  </script>




</head>



<body class="animate-in">

<!-- NAV-->


<div class="artist-name">  <a class="navbar-brand " href="index.html" >KOUSHNA NAVABI</a> </div>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid ">
    <button class="navbar-toggler " type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 mx-auto text-center menupoints justify-content-center">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="projects.html">Exhibitions</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link mx-2" href="archive.html">Project Archive</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link mx-2" href="texts.html">Texts</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link mx-2" href="publications.html">Publications</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link mx-2" href="editions.html">Editions</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link mx-2" href="about.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link mx-2" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- YEAR SLIDER-->

<section class="container-fluid year-slider-container bg-white" id="year-slider-container">
 <div class="row year-slider align-items-center"  >
     <div class="col-12 col-sm-2 col-xl-4  offset-xl-1">
      <section>
        <label class="d-none d-md-block" for="amount"> Years:</label>
        <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0;">
      </section>
    </div>

   <div class="col-11 col-sm-8 col-md-7 col-xl-6 mx-auto p-md-1"> <div id="slider-range"></div></div>
 </div>
</section>




<!-- PORTFOLIO STARTS HERE/////////////////////////////////////////////////////-->



<div class="portfolio-wrapper" style="padding-top: 12rem; overflow-y: scroll; height: 300vh; background: yellow;" >


  <section class="container-fluid portfolio-main  " >

       <!-- content-->
      
    
 
  </section>

</div>


 <!-- Year slider script show/hide based on year range-->


<script>
  $( "#slider-range" ).on( "slidechange", function( event, ui ) {
    console.log(ui.values);

    // hide all
    $('.content-photo').hide();

    // loop between min and max and select and show the ones the exist
    min = ui.values[0];
    max = ui.values[1];
    for(var value=min;value<=max;value++) {
        var divElement = $("div[data-time='"+ value +"']");
        if(divElement) {
            divElement.fadeIn(700);
        }
    }
});

</script>

<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Lightbox-->
   <script src="js/bootstrap-lightbox.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/index.bundle.min.js">
    
const options = {
    keyboard: true,
    size: 'sm'
};
  </script>





/* YEAR SLIDER SCROLL HIDE */

<script>
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("year-slider-container").style.top = "5rem";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("year-slider-container").style.top = "-50px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
} 
</script>


<!-- HTML FADE -->

<script>
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function () {
  document.body.classList.add("animate-out");
});
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I have a horizontal element that (.year-slider) that appears on top of the screen under the top menu, but when people scroll down it hides itself under that bar. When they scroll up again, the element comes back.

I came up with this code, that works perfectly on my laptop:

```
<script>
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("year-slider-container").style.top = "5rem";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("year-slider-container").style.top = "-50px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
} 
</script>
```

But it for some reason doesn't work on a macbook nor on my Iphone: the element acts weird, then when you scroll down and up, it kind of jumps out of screen.

What could it be?

Comment: Please make a working demo of this for the question.  use the snippet tool (the button looks like `[<>]`)

Comment: Okay, made one and added it above